# Setting starting date per ID (with different starting dates)- R

Tags: r

I would like to set a starting date per ID so that I could compute dependent variables that are the following:
1- the number of weeks per year where individuals weighed themselves 6+ times.
2- the avg number of days per week where individuals engaged in self-weighing per year.
The dataset has weight measurements from 2021 to 2023 for different participants.

Dataset:

| ID | Weight | Timestamp | Day | Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 2021/05/05 | 18752 | 202118 |
| 1 | 205 | 2021/05/06 | 18753 | 202118 |
| 1 | 203 | 2021/05/10 | 18757 | 202119 |
| 2 | 170 | 2021/05/05 | 18752 | 202118 |
| 2 | 177 | 2021/05/06 | 18753 | 202118 |

my approach is to create a loop where after assigning a starting date for each ID, I could ask it to check for measurements for 365 (including the starting date) and exclude the rest. from there I would be able to compute my 2 variables. However, I am not sure how to execute this in code.
I expect the results to include:

| ID | Number of weeks/ year with 6+ | Avg number of days/week over 1 year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | example: 35/52 | example: 4.3/7 |
| 2 | example: 23/52 | example: 3.5/7 |

Comment: not so sure what you are looking for here. For the first timestamp for every ID, you can use dplyr with `group_by(ID) %>% summarise(startingdate = min(timestamp))`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you need a starting date and a loop to get to your expected results. I guess that you are looking for something along those lines:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  # Create the year variable as the first 4 characters of Timestamp
  mutate(year = substr(Timestamp, 1, 4)) %>%
  # Separately for each ID/year/week...
  group_by(ID, year, Week) %>%
  # ...compute number of weightings per week
  summarise(n_per_week = n()) %>%
  # Separately for each ID/year...
  group_by(ID, year) %>% 
  # ...compute the variables of interest
  summarise(weeks_min_6 = paste0(sum(n_per_week > 6), "/52"),
            avg_days_per_week = paste0(round(sum(n_per_week)/52, 1), "/7")) %>%
  # Ungroup the data
  ungroup()
```